# Change the default string xml file in android

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, android-resources, string.xml

I started working in my application using English strings for my string resources file, but now I created an Arabic string file , and i want to use this string resources as the default language for my app. 
is it possible to change the default string resource file now ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> i want to use this string resources as the default language for my app

Put those strings in the `res/values/` directory. Put the English strings in `res/values-en/`. At that point, devices configured with English as the locale will use your English strings, and all other devices will use your Arabic strings.